# Remove duplicate result in django search

Tags: python, django

I hope you're well. Does anyone know how I can remove duplicate in search result? For instance, if i search "Louis". I got 4 duplicates results. Is there any way to got unique result? thanks in advance.

user/views.py

```
#search profile
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/earlycooker/login/'),name="dispatch")
class UserProfileResultsView(ListView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'search_results_user.html' 
    
    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = UserProfile.objects.filter(
            Q(pays__icontains=query) | Q(town__icontains=query) | Q(user__username__icontains=query) | Q(mealtrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(pricetrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(speedtrend__name__icontains=query)| Q(strengthtrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(wellnesstrend__name__icontains=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

templates/search_result_user.html

```
 {% for userprofile in object_list %}
  
  <a href="{% url 'user:user_public_cookwall' slug=userprofile.user.userprofile.slug %}" class="search_user_link">{{ userprofile.user.username }}</a> 
    
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Add .distinct()  to query

Comment: thanks :) if anyone needs:

    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = UserProfile.objects.filter(
            Q(pays__icontains=query) | Q(town__icontains=query) | Q(user__username__icontains=query) | Q(mealtrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(pricetrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(speedtrend__name__icontains=query)| Q(strengthtrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(wellnesstrend__name__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
        return object_list

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate duplicate rows from the query results use the distinct() method provided by Django.

> distinct(*fields)
>
> Returns a new QuerySet that uses SELECT DISTINCT in
> its SQL query. This eliminates duplicate rows from the query results.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

You can use it as follows:

```
object_list = UserProfile.objects.filter(...).distinct()
```